# Type '[String, AnyObject?]' does not conform to protocol AnyObject?: why?

Tags: dictionary, swift, compiler-errors, nsdictionary, literals

I'm trying to understand why I have a compilation error: **Type '[String, AnyObject?]' does not conform to protocol AnyObject?**

```
var cars: [String: AnyObject?] = [ "model": "Ferrari"]
var JSON: [String: AnyObject?] = [ "cars": cars ]  // <-- error
```

It seems like `cars` is not an AnyObject? which I don't understand.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`AnyObject` must be a class, but `Dictionary` is a structure.

#### [The Swift Programming Language: Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

> AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.

#### [The Swift Programming Language: Classes and Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_135)

> Swift’s String, Array, and Dictionary types are implemented as structures.

---

You can use `Any?` for this purpose.

```
var cars: [String: Any?] = [ "model": "Ferrari"]
var JSON: [String: Any?] = [ "cars": cars ]
```

---

After looking at this a bit more, there is a subtle problem which causes this to break.

Here is a sample which works:

```
var cars: [String: AnyObject] = [ "model": "Ferrari"]
var JSON: [String: AnyObject] = [ "cars": cars ]
```

It works because `cars` is coerced (implicitly cast) from `[String: AnyObject]` to an object compatible with `NSDictionary ([AnyHashable: AnyObject])`. This `NSDictionary` compatible object is then cast to `AnyObject`. So, magic.

`[String: AnyObject?]` cannot be cast in this way because it not `NSDictionary` compatible, so the coercion fails.

Comment: Thanks! Will that impact the casting of my object towards a NSDictionary?

Comment: You will already have a problem. `NSDictionary` must be `[NSObject: AnyObject]`. `[NSObject: AnyObject?]` will not work.

Comment: Fixed a minor mistake `NSDictionary` is coerced to `[AnyHashable: AnyObject]`.

Answer (score 3):

> It seems like cars is not an AnyObject?

You defined `cars` as of type `[String: AnyObject?]`, thus, the following code  is valid (tested in Playground):

```
var cars: [String: AnyObject?] = [ "model": "Ferrari"]
var JSON: [String: [String: AnyObject?]] = [ "cars": cars ]
```

You should define `JSON` as of type `[String: AnyObject?]` or `[String: Any?]` (according to your needs) only if you can't guess what type `cars` will be (see [Type Casting for Any and AnyObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) in *The Swift Programming Language*).

> Will that impact the casting of my object towards a NSDictionary?

`NSDictionary` can't hold `nil` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008365/ios-why-cant-i-set-nil-to-nsdictionary-value) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824999/how-does-nsdictionary-handle-nil-objects)). The following code gives an error message in Playground:

```
var nsDict1: NSDictionary = [12 : 10, 10 : nil] //eror message

var cars: [String: AnyObject?] = [ "model" : nil]
var JSON: [String: [String: AnyObject?]] = [ "cars" : cars ]
let nsDict2 = JSON as NSDictionary //error message
```

However, the following code is valid:

```
var nsDict1: NSDictionary = [12 : 10, 10 : NSNull()] //no error message

var cars: [String: AnyObject] = [ "model" : "Ferrari"] //also works with [ "model" : NSNull()]
var JSON: [String: [String: AnyObject]] = [ "cars" : cars ]

let nsDict2 = JSON as NSDictionary //no error message
```

Comment: >NSDictionary can't hold nil. 
Have to remember it.