# Cannot pass array into performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, arrays, swift2

I want to pass an array named products of type [Product] through `performSegueWithIdentifier(self.segueName, sender: products)`

I want to receive the array in the `sender` parameter of `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)`

However, this does not compile: `Cannot convert value of type '[Product]' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'`

Why do I want to do this? Simply because I want to avoid adding a global variable in my Controller class for this purpose.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried to convert the array to `AnyObject` beforehand. This solution compiles but the resulting value in the `sender` parameter in the `prapareForSegue` function contains `nil`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == segueName {
        let productsController = segue.destinationViewController as! ProductsController
        productsController.products = sender as! [Product]
    }
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let company = DataService.allCompanies[indexPath.item]
    DataService.getAllProductsForCompanies([company]) { (products: [Product]) -> () in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("getAllProductsForCompanies for companyId: \(company.companyId)")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.segueName, sender: products as? AnyObject)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was that I had declared my Product entity as a struct and not a class. This prevented the array to be handled as an AnyObject.

Using a class allowed me to pass `[Product]` into `performSegueWithIdentifier` without any type casting and the received parameter was successfully cast back again using `sender as! [Product]`

Answer (score 2):

Directly from the Swift Programming Language reference:

> The as? version of the downcast operator returns an optional value of the protocol’s type, and this value is nil if the instance does not conform to that protocol.

So if the value you are getting is nil, it means `[Product]` does not conform to `AnyObject?` protocol which is expected since `[Product]` is an array (see here: [Structures as AnyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997376/type-string-anyobject-does-not-conform-to-protocol-anyobject-why)).

What you can do is typecast `[Product]` to NSArray, since that is an object that conforms to AnyObject?.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier(self.segueName, sender: (products as NSArray) as? AnyObject)
```

Look here for more: [AnyObject to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097982/anyobject-to-array).

Let me know how it goes! Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Adam. My problem was solved by my answer below. Your answer was good but it must contain some errors since I never needed any type casting at all in the final solution.

Comment: I made the assumption that your Product entity was a class. Glad you found the answer!